# Why can't I get the correct result when the same character is repeated a lot in the character count in the string?

Tags: string, count, conditional-statements, abap

I can't get the correct result when the same character is repeated too many times in the string expression in ABAP.

When it is more than 10, the repeating character gives * instead of number as a result.

output : `*WB2W3B4WB`

expected output : `12WB2W3B4WB`

```
DATA(input) = 'WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWBWWBBBWWWWB'.
DATA(count) = 1.
DATA result TYPE string.

DO strlen( input ) - 1 TIMES.

  DATA(lv_single1) = substring( val = input off = sy-index - 1 len = 1 ).
  DATA(lv_single2) = substring( val = input off = sy-index  len = 1 ).

  IF lv_single1 = lv_single2.
    count = count + 1.
  ELSE.
    result = |{ result }{  COND #( WHEN count = 1 THEN '' ELSE count  ) }{ lv_single1 }|.
    count = 1.
  ENDIF.

ENDDO.

result = |{ result }{ COND #( WHEN count = 1 THEN '' ELSE count ) }{ lv_single2 }|.
```

Comment: If you debug your program in order to make it a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), you would end in a more interesting question `DATA(count) = 16. DATA(result) = ||. result = |{ COND #( WHEN count = 1 THEN '' ELSE count  ) }|. result = COND #( WHEN count = 1 THEN '' ELSE count  ).` Why first `result` is `*` and second one is `16`?

Answer (score 6):

The problem lays in the automatic type inference for the result of the conditional operator `COND`.

You used **COND `#`(** ... **)**
`#` means that you *did not specify* a concrete non-generic data type for the result and in this case an operand with a statically identifiable type must be specified after the first `THEN`.

After `THEN` you used `''` literal, which results in a type being inferred as **C(1)**. When you assign afterwards to this type a `count` variable, which has the type **I(4)** and its value requires more than 1 character space, the asterisk **`*`** is written as a single character value.

> The exact rule for the conversion when the **source type is `integer`** b (1-byte), s (1-2-bytes), i (4-bytes) or int8 (8-bytes) and **target type is `c`** character-like:
> ... if the target field **is longer** than the string of digits, including the plus/minus sign, *it is padded* with blanks on the left. If it **is too short**, the number representation is moved to the right by one place for positive values. If the target field is still too short (and for negative values), it is truncated on the left and the *character* **`*`** *is set* in the first position of the target field.

To solve the issue use any suitable type for the result of the COND operator, for example :

```
  " define some fixed-length character type
  TYPES: tt_char4(4) TYPE c.
  
  ... COND tt_char4( ... ) ...

  " or use string or some type defined in DDIC
  ... COND string( ... ) ...
  ... COND char4( ... ) ...
```

Note that using character-like types may introduce additional spaces, which would need to be removed later (the result of type `string` includes trailing spaces but a fixed-length character type does not include them).
You can also just use:

```
   ... COND i( ... ) ...
```

(i.e. just replace in your code `#` with `i`).

Additional information is available at: [COND, Conditional Operator](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_latest_index_htm/latest/en-us/abenconditional_expression_cond.htm), [CONV, Type Inference for Actual Parameters](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_latest_index_htm/latest/en-us/abenconv_constructor_inference.htm)

Comment: You are basically right, but just use integer as type: COND i( ... ). Using string or charatcer types will add some unnecessary spaces into the string, which have to be removed later.

Comment: Thank you for the note, you are right - updated the answer with this information.